# `requests.get` object, attempting to parse `xml` into `pandas.DataFrame`

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have successfully created a `requests.get(url)` object from [Zillow's Get Region Children API](http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetRegionChildren.htm), created using the following:

```
import requests

In [103]: socket = requests.get(''http://www.zillow.com/...neighborhood')
```

When I examine what is in the `socket` object, I get lots of content, of which I'll share just the beginning:

```
In [106]: socket.content
Out[106]: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RegionChildren:regionchildren
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/RegionChildren.xsd 
http://www.zillowstatic.com/vstatic/479fdf9/static/xsd/RegionChildren.xsd"  
xmlns:RegionChildren="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/RegionChildren.xsd"><request>
<state>wa</state><city>seattle</city><childtype>neighborhood</childtype></request>
<message><text>Request successfully processed</text><code>0</code></message><response>
<region><id>16037</id><latitude>47.559364</latitude><longitude>-122.313752</longitude>
</region><subregiontype>neighborhood</subregiontype><list><count>107</count><region>
<id>250206</id><name>Capitol Hill</name><zindex currency="USD">398000</zindex>
<url>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/WA-Seattle/Capitol-Hill/r_250206/</url>...'
```

I have been to the [`xml.etree.ElementTree` Tutorial Page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree), where they illustrate parsing an `xml` file.  It appears as though (based on the documentation), that this should be the appropriate way to parse the string:

```
import lxml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [107]: root = ET.fromstring(socket.content)
```

However, I'm still unable to access any of the tag elements (`<zindex>`, `<name>`, `<region><id>`, etc.) using any of the next steps provided in the tutorial, for example, I get the following:

```
In [112]: root.tag
Out[112]: '{http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/RegionChildren.xsd}regionchildren'

In [114]: for child in root:
          print child.tag, child.attrib
.....: 
request {}
message {}
response {}
```

I'd like to be able to iterate over all of the different tag elements, place them into a `dict` or `pandas.DataFrame`, but I can't get the first step of actually accessing the elements.

Comment: How can you put all tags to a dict? There must be multiple tags with a similar name..

Comment: I tried to give all the tags above, in my line of XML, sorry for poorly displaying it.  They are:<region><id><latitude><longitude><list><count><name><zindex><url>.  There's over 100 entries, each which has those tags (the same as above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I was able to get the desired result by using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).  Specifically the following:

### Step 1:

Load the data in to a `bs4` object, as specifically suggested [where the parsing libraries are described](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

```
[In] 10: soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(socket.content, ['lxml', 'xml'])
```

### Step 2:

Take a look at the mess of `xml` data to ascertain the structure of it.

```
[In] 11: f = open('pretty_xml.xml', 'w')
[In] 12: f.writelines(soup.prettify())
[In] 13: f.close()
```

### Step 3:

Begin the extraction

Once the data is viewed more carefully, use the `bs4.findChildren()` functionality to extract each node into the cell of a list.  For example:

```
[In] 14: soup_list = soup.findChildren()
```

Then (assuming the `tags` are the same for each of the list elements, or mostly similar as in my case), create a `(index, values)` pairing using the [`text` and `name` attributes of `bs4.tag`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) elements, doing something like this:

```
[In] 15: d = {}
[In] 16: for i, element in enumerate(soup_list):
...:        index = map(lambda x: x.name, element.findChildren())
...:        vals = map(lambda x: unicode(x.text), element.findChildren())
...:        d[i] = pandas.Series(vals, index = index)
```

Then you're all setup to make a `pandas.DataFrame` passing the `dict` of `Series`.

Comment: Great explanation. I know this was a while ago but how did you go about doing the last passing the dict of series?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about creating the final `DataFrame` (correct?), which in this case would just be, `df = pandas.DataFrame(d).transpose()`

Comment: Yes I am working on a similar problem but cannot get around the duplicate columns issue. Would I transpose it within the DataFrame? aka ' df= pd.DataFrame(d.transpose())?